# Carousel issue with overflow-y on Firefox

Tags: angular, materialize

Steps to reproduce:

- run and open in fulls-creen with **Firefox**: 
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eaabvd
- after it renders, open the element inspector (F12), and close it.
- **Surprise**! the box three and two are shrink! the page will look like this:

[image]

Does anyone have experienced this behavior? Is it a bug in Firefox or Materialize? Does Anyone know a good workaround?

It doesn't happen only when opening object inspector, but also when we do "routing" to this view.